# How to detect if a PWA using window-controls-overlay is installed

Tags: javascript, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

When using a PWA in `"display_override": ["window-controls-overlay"]`, it seems to be impossible to detect if the PWA is installed, without the user clicking on the arrow up button [The arrow button in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmYUX.png)

If they don't I don't seem to be able to detect that it is installed without hacks like setting a questionmark parameter (`/?pwa=true`), which isn't ideal as someone could share a link and then the in-browser version would think it is in PWA mode

I need to detect if I am a PWA since I want to indicate to the user that a rich titlebar is available

My manifest is

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SchemaStore/schemastore/master/src/schemas/json/web-manifest.json",
    "display": "standalone",
    "display_override": ["window-controls-overlay", "standalone"],
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "/img/icons/android-chrome-192x192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "/img/icons/android-chrome-512x512.png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/png"
        }
    ],
    "lang": "en",
    "name": "Insert name",
    "scope": "/",
    "short_name": "Insert short name",
    "start_url": "/",
    "theme_color": "#212529",
    "background_color": "#212529"
}
```

I have tried using these methods:

- `"standalone" in window.navigator`
- `(window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches`

There don't seem to be any other methods used on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do should work. Just tried it on my test WCO app. So in JavaScript you can query the following:

```
// True when WCO toggle is off (since it's your back-up display-mode):
window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches

// True when WCO toggle is on:
window.matchMedia('(display-mode: window-controls-overlay)').matches

// True when you haven't yet installed the app and are inside the browser:
window.matchMedia('(display-mode: browser)').matches
```

Or similarly in CSS:

```
@media (display-mode: standalone) {

}

@media (display-mode: window-controls-overlay) {

}

@media (display-mode: browser) {

}
```

If you are using chrome, the support for detecting `window-controls-overlay` was landed in version 105.0.5189.0 so you check your browser's version from chrome://version. I think what you are looking for is [here](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:chrome/browser/web_applications/web_app_registrar.cc;drc=c410120011084508641f34a24d77d7625bd4f4bf;l=532) in Chromium code.